# What would it be like to have your hand chopped off by an axe?

Tags: anatomy, medicine, blood

A child character in my book was caught stealing food for their parents and the people who caught them chop off their right hand with an axe as a lesson to "keep their dirty hands off".

I've fortunately never had a body part decapitated so I don't know what it's like. I want to know how I would describe the pain and image of what it would be like. Morbid, I know, I just want it to be realistic.

Also, approx. how long would it take for a child-sized human to bleed out after that? If their hand is cut clean off, the blood would drain from the veins and arteries and stuff (or maybe it would just clot, I'm not sure) How fast would that happen and what's the best way death could be prevented?

And lastly, the character is supposed to survive and get aid by another. This part doesn't have to be answered, but how would the process of stitching or surgery work?

Comment: Hi and welcome Beeshball. There are limits to questions in here, please look closely at [our guide to topics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. This looks like you want to write a story and need help describing some sensation your character has. That would be better for the Writing stack exchange. Here we simply help with building worlds around the characters. You can take as long as you like to edit this, but it may be closed until it fits our format.

Comment: Hellow Beeshballl, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please take a moment to take our [tour] and read through our [help]. As you can imagine, yours isn't the first question about violence and the infliction of pain on this site. It happens. However, [Stack Exchange has decreed that there are limits](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/40609), so you should be aware that your question isn't salvageable. We can answer clinical questions about violence - but that's it. Finally, you are allowed to ask only one question per post. SE is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @beeshballl   Otto of the Silver Hand is a children's historical novel set in the Middle Ages written and illustrated by Howard Pyle.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_of_the_Silver_Hand    The main character, a child named Otto, acquires a hand made of silver to replace the one which is cut off. So maybe there is a description of what hand cutting off feels like and first aid proceedures in that novel.

Comment: There are enough examples of people losing a limb due to bombings, auto accidents, etc. that dealing with amputation is part of EMT training. Do a search on EMT training and amputation to learn more. People do die because of blood loss but using a tourniquet has been known since ancient times.